# C# SQL Login that uses somekind of authentication

Tags: c#, sql

I'm in the need of some help probably because I can't express very well what I want on google.

```
    private void LogInBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string conString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=H:\Jogos.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand log = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Funcionario WHERE [e-mail] ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = log.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            count += 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Succesfull");
            if ()
            {
                Form menu = new MenuPrincipalAdmin();
                menu.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }

            else
            {
                Form menu = new MenuPrincipalFunc();
                menu.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
        else if (count > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate e-mail and password.");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("E-mail or Password invalid.");
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        con.Close();
    }
```

After the "Login Sucessfull" message box I wanted to make something like if permission = Admin then  opens the AdminMenu else opens the WorkerMenu.

I think it's possible but not sure since I can't get my mind over it.

Comment: you can add a combo box to select from ..for eg : admin or user ,then check in if condition

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM Funcionario WHERE [e-mail] ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'"` Was your first programming language PHP? Please use parameters.

Comment: And hash and salt and pepper those password.

Comment: Your code won't work? What is `MenuPrincipalAdmin` exactly? You should always use parameterized queries by the way? This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks. And don't store your passwords as a plain text. Also use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Comment: Don't use the `AttachDbFileName=` and `UserInstance=true` features anymore - they cause a lot of confusion and grief, and will be removed from SQL Server in a future version anyway - better stay away from it today already! See Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits : Using AttachDBFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info on this.

Comment: in which table/column you save permission details of user?

Comment: Forgive me for saying this, but I don't think you're prepared to be coding interactions with databases (your code is SQL-injection-friendly) and user login/authentication for a production system *yet*. You need to start by *validating inputs*, one of the most basic principles in programming. Then read up on security and encrypting the connection between your application and database to *not* send user credentials in the clear, etc. This is serious stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to learn, how the Auth works on the sample ASP.Net application in Visual Studio (it would be the same in MVC and WinForms).
Then you could use that approach and similar DB in your application. It is really common functionality nowadays so there is no need to invent anything here.

Generally, it shouldn't be possible to store duplicated logins (and of cause login+password) in your database. You should use constraints for it.

For the logic below you should use Roles. For instance, you could use Users-UsersInRoles-Roles DB structure.

```
        if ()
        {
            Form menu = new MenuPrincipalAdmin();
            menu.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        else
        {
            Form menu = new MenuPrincipalFunc();
            menu.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```